# Android SDK MonkeyRunner 25.3.2 Won't Run

Tags: monkeyrunner

So I upgraded Android SDK tools today and now I'm having a problem getting monkeyrunner to run.  I did the standard which is (from the command prompt)

```
D:\Android\SDK\tools\bin\monkeyrunner.bat D:\ScriptName.py
```

Note 1: The directory of monkeyrunner.bat changed in this release, so I had to update my command line accordingly.

That fails with the message:

```
SWT Folder '..\framework\x86_64' does not exist.
```

I can fix that by editing monkeyrunner.bat and instead of having frameworkdir be set to 'lib' it gets set to '..\lib', the actual location of the monkey runner jar file.

However, when I implement this fix it then gives the error:

```
Cannot run program "..\framework\adb.exe" cannot find the file specified.
```

I'm kind of stuck here because no matter what I change in monkeyrunner.bat I get the same message, which indicates to me that the jar file has this directory hardcoded in it or something.  It should probably be "....\platform-tools\adb.exe"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can't find a solution you may try [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which is a drop-in replacement for most of the cases

Answer (score 12):

-open monkeyrunner.bat in notepad

- change `set frameworkdir=.` to `set frameworkdir=..\lib` everywhere
- find the line `call "%java_exe%" -Xmx512m "-Djava.ext.dirs=%frameworkdir%;%swt_path%" -Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir= -jar %jarpath% %*`
- change the value of `Dcom.android.monkeyrunner.bindir` to the path of the folder containing adb.exe. Mine was under platform-tools